# ng-show/ng-hide não atualiza index-html, somente a view

Tags: angularjs

Estou montando uma aplicação que possui uma index.html e as views em arquivos separados sendo renderizadas dentro do ng-view da index.

Nessa index eu tenho um footer que eu gostaria que desaparecesse quando o usuário fosse encaminhado para a view home, após realizado o login.

O problema é que o ng-hide desse footer não está pegando o valor atual da variável "autenticado" após a realização do login, o que faz o usuário ser encaminhado para a home, mas com o footer ainda aparecendo.

Como faço pra a variável ser atualizada e o footer sumir? Para variáveis que são utilizadas dentro da view, o ng-hide/ng-show funciona corretamente, só não está funcionando para essa parte estática da index.

index.hmtl

```html
<html ng-app="gameApp">

<head>
 <!-- referências de css e scripts  -->
</head>

<body>

  <div id="main" class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
  
  <footer ng-hide="autenticado">
    teste
  </footer>
  
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```js
var ggApp = angular.module('gameApp', ['ngRoute', 'servicoLogin']);

 // configure our routes
 ggApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

   // route for the home page
   .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/login.html',
    controller  : 'usuarioController',
    controllerAs  : 'loginCtrl'
   })
   // route for the about page
   .when('/cadastro', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/cadastroUsuario.html',
    controller  : 'usuarioController',
    controllerAs  : 'loginCtrl'
   })

   // route for the contact page
   .when('/home', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
    controller  : 'homeController',
    controllerAs  : 'homeCtrl'
   })
   .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
   });
 });
```

usuarioController.js

```js
ggApp.controller("usuarioController", ['$scope', 'Login', 'Cadastro', 'VerificaEmail', '$location', 
                                       function($scope, Login, Cadastro, VerificaEmail, $location) {
  
 $scope.erro = false;
 $scope.mostraMensagem = false;
 $scope.mensagemErro = "teste";
 $scope.autenticado = false;
 
 this.usuarioLogin = {};
 
 this.realizaLogin = function() {
  
  var usuario = {
    email: this.usuarioLogin.login,
    senha: this.usuarioLogin.senha
  }
  
  var promise = Login.login(usuario);
  
  promise.$promise.then( 
    function success(usuario)
    {
     if (usuario.id > 0) {
      $location.path("home");
      $scope.autenticado = true;
     } else {
      $scope.erro = true;
      $scope.mensagemErro = "Usuário não encontrado!";
     };
     $scope.mostraMensagem = true;
     $scope.setClasseErro();
     
    },
    function error(value) {
     $scope.erro = true;
     $scope.mostraMensagem = true;
     $scope.mensagemErro = "Erro: " + value.status;
    }
  );
  
  
 };
}]);
```

Comment: Você pode verificar parâmetros quando trocar de rota, verificando se deve exibir ou não o footer. Ou colocar a variável autenticado no rootScope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O escopo do `ngView` e do seu `footer` são diferentes. Por isso não funciona. A variável `autenticado` se quer existe no escopo do `footer`.

Veja essa resposta do SO em inglês, ela utiliza `$scope.$broadcast` para fazer comunicação entre controllers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446755/on-and-broadcast-in-angular

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: Só mais uma coisa: nesse caso, quando aperto F5 para atualizar a página o escopo se reinicia e a variável passa a ter seu valor original ou fica undefined. Existe uma maneira de tornar isso uma variável de sessão? Existe esse conceito em Angular?

Comment: Não existe esse conceito devido a forma como Javascript trabalha. Cada refresh de página, é uma instância completamente nova de um "programa". Mas você pode implementar algo semelhante utilizando cookies. Veja a documentação em: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie Só gostaria de destacar que o controle de se um usuário esta logado ou não na aplicação não deve ser feito do lado do cliente, e sim do lado do servidor.